# Nmap not returning network protocol

Tags: nmap, python

I'm playing with Nmap in Python and after running these commands:

```
import nmap

nm = nmap.PortScanner()
nm.all_hosts()  # returns 127.0.0.1
nm['127.0.0.1'].all_protocols() #  returns an empty list []
```

I thought network protocol always has to be either TCP or UDP 
but how can I be getting nothing from Nmap ?

Comment: you should do a `scan` first

Comment: You're right. I should've ran `nm.scan('127.0.0.1', '22-443')` after the first command. Still not getting any protocol though.